# Appcelerator - default splash screen doesn't fit on android and cut from bottom

Tags: android, splash-screen, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I am having a very strange problem all of a sudden for some time. I have always used the single default.png image for splash screen in android and it always worked great but for past some time I noticed that now the splash screen doesn't fit and show cutted from bottom.

I created a new blank default project and run it on genymotion emulator and following is the result:

Splash screen image (default.png):

[image]

App splash screen:
[image]

I've tried it on Genymotion emulator

```
Google Nexus 5X - 6.0.0 - API 23 - 1080x1920
Google Nexus 4 - 5.1.0 - API 22 - 768x1280
```

I've tried it running with SDKs 5.1.0.GA, 5.1.2.GA, 5.2.0.GA, 5.2.2.GA, 5.3.0.v20160421080259 and 5.4.0.v20160608165242 with no luck :(

iPhone works perfectly. This bug came all of a sudden and I really have no clue what could be the problem. Please help!!!

Comment: check real android device and also show your xml code and screenshot

Comment: You're using ImageView for this image? If yes, use proper scaleType. If you're using it as layout background, make sure it is with the parent layout with match_parent width and height

Comment: @YasirTahir Its splash screen, not an image

Comment: @SathishKumarJ It also happens on some real devices. Screenshot is attached in question. Same thing happens on device.

Comment: share your xml code for the splash screen.

Comment: @AshishRanjan There is no xml code. I am using the default.png image provided by appcelerator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found the problem. The default.png works perfectly. Looks like the navigation bar in Nexus devices is the culprit which appears on top of splash screen so it looks cutted/stretched. The issue is reported here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19769

The workaround is to set `<fullscreen>false</fullscreen>` to true in tiapp.xml

Answer (score 0):

I had expected the image to be stretched, but both stretching and cropping splash images that don't 100% match the device screen ratio are not ideal. That's why both Android and Appcelerator recommend using 9-patch images.

See the [guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Icons_and_Splash_Screens-section-29004897_IconsandSplashScreens-Androidsplashscreenconsiderations) and the 4.x and 5.x sample apps which also use 9-patch (contrary to the default template atm unfortunately).

Comment: Hmmm....I also felt that but why this "stretching" thing started occuring all of a sudden? And that too on even old SDKs so its not related to a bug in a newer SDK. I have been using the simple default.png for almost 3-4 years without any problems. Also is this problem common or is it happening to me only? I wonder if this is something to do with Android version, Genymotion version or emulator configurations.